# Multiple pages with different functionality

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest

I am currently working on a layout project for Smartphones and tablets in Eclipse (Java). I followed the instructions on the developers site, how to create different layouts for different screens and this works just fine.

The problem I am having is that I want different buttons in different layouts, when I remove 1 button from, lets say my Smartphone version but I want to use it in my tablet version, the Smartphone version crashes because in the MainActivity.java it calls for a button he can't find.

I tried to solve the problem by creating a different mainActivity page for every device, but I cant figure out wether it is possible to create multiple launchpages with different names in the AndroidManifest depending on the device that is currently used.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If its a different button but a button still exists, then you could just initialize the variable to reference that other button and the code should still work.

If the behaviour is not the same, then you could have a base class which contains most of the common code, and 2 subclasses one for each layout.

Comment: I solved the problem by changing his visibility to 'gone' and putting a different button as a replacement, this works. It does create the button but in my layout it doesnt exist, this makes it possible to put another button in the same place without making the layout larger. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you might be giving different id for different buttons in different layout File. Change the drawable/style as per the layout-folder but keep the id same for all the buttons in difefrent layouts.

Comment: Hi Ritaban, The buttons have the same ID in every layout because some I wish to use in every layout, the problem is that when I don't want a particular button in one of my layouts, he crashes, because the button is called but in my layout it doesnt exist. But I found a solution that works for me! Thank you for your awnser.

Comment: Then you can dynamically add buttons through code by checking the configuration like    if((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >=Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE){
   boolean largescreen=true;
  }

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using [AndroidQuery](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/) for this purpose. It support multiple ui implementation in one simple code.

```
public void renderContent(Content content, View view) {

        //this is a phone!

        //this view exists
        aq.id(R.id.textInMobileLayoutOnly).text("Welcome to my Mobile App!");

        //this button exist in tablet layout only, but it's ok
        //AQuery will ignore all the operations on this view
        aq.id(R.id.butttonInTabletOnly).text("Open a new tab!");        

}
```